# "Why are some questions closed?" should link to "Help: Question closed"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, faq-content

[The FAQ list's section on "Why are some questions closed?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#close) should link to ["Help: Question closed"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed), a useful page that is otherwise fairly hard to find. Specifically, I propose that the FAQ-list text

> See [How to Ask](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for guidance on editing your question to improve it.

be changed to

> See [How to Ask](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for guidance on editing your question to improve it, and [Help—Question closed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed) for help with getting it reopened.

or the like.